# How to get total system RAM in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

As the title says, is there a way to get the total (installed) system RAM in .NET Standard 2.0?  All my searches only turn up with .NET Framework solutions.

Comment: OS switch or no-go. Which way do you want to go today?

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?  It's a legitimate question.  I indicated that I researched this.  My question is clear and concise.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want.  Do you want to know why you can't do this with .netstandard?  Easy answer, but won't help you at all.  Do you want somebody to write code for you that is portable on any OS that .net supports?  That is not going to happen, so won't help you at all.  Do you want advice to avoid needing this method?  Easy answer yet again, any OS already provides this info so you don't have to yourself.  So why does this problem need be solved?  It is impossible to see from the question.

Comment: What do you consider RAM? Is swap space/page file included in that?

Comment: @HansPassant I thought it was very clear what I want.  I asked a yes or no question and was expecting a yes or no response.  It's not my fault if the reader overthinks it and makes assumptions.  For reference, I'm rewriting a Windows service that I used in https://instatech.lucent.rocks/.  I'm pulling out as much of the code as I can into a .NET Standard library.  The rest will be left in the Windows implementation.

Comment: @itsme86 (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory

Comment: Install this: [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/). Lightweight. Windows only.

Comment: @Jimi  Thanks.  That's what I'm currently using for WMI queries on the Windows service.  :)

Comment: That's the .Net Standard 2.0/Core 2.1 extension.

Comment: @Jimi Oh, gotcha!  Thanks.  :)

Comment: Does "new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory" work in .Net 2.0 Standard?

Comment: This is what I ended up building: https://remotely.one/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/) with NET Standard 2.0. Hope this can help you:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

namespace RamSystem
{
    public class RamSystem
    {
        public static void GetRAM()
        {
            ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
            ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

            double res;

            foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
            {
                res = Convert.ToDouble(result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]);
                double fres = Math.Round((res / (1024 * 1024)), 2);
                Console.WriteLine("Total usable memory size: " + fres + "GB");
                Console.WriteLine("Total usable memory size: " + res + "KB");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```